# Centering overlapping images while window re-sizes

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images of identical size that need to overlap perfectly and remain overlapped while the window re-sizes. For some reason, setting position: absolute; reverses the centering.
Here is the code so far, i've replaced my images with generic ones found on google images.

```
<img src = "http://www.brittlestar.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/300x300.gif" width = 50%  height = auto style="position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
<img src = "https://www.leadheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/superforms/2018/07/883153652/5361c9b53077aa52c50fa005b15c6c4f%20(2)-300x300.png" width = 50% height = auto style = "position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
```

How to fix this?

Comment: show us the parent element too

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a container box that contains your two images and add `position: relative`  to that box. Also you can use **flex** to center the content of the box. Finally add `position: absolute` to the image you want to overlap.  Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.container img.overlap {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/c9c9c9/fff">
  <img class="overlap" src="https://www.leadheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/superforms/2018/07/883153652/5361c9b53077aa52c50fa005b15c6c4f%20(2)-300x300.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.overlap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">
  <img class="overlap" src="https://www.leadheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/superforms/2018/07/883153652/5361c9b53077aa52c50fa005b15c6c4f%20(2)-300x300.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep one image as div background and another as content of the div

HTML

```css
.imageCont{background: url('http://www.brittlestar.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/300x300.gif') center no-repeat; width:300px; height:300px;display:flex; align-items:center;justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div class="imageCont">
<img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the codes provided by you, you can use the code below to achieve the desired output.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.brittlestar.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/300x300.gif" style="position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
    <img src="https://www.leadheroes.com/wp-content/uploads/superforms/2018/07/883153652/5361c9b53077aa52c50fa005b15c6c4f%20(2)-300x300.png" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: calc(50% - 150px);">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can do this while still specifying the width of the image? adjusting the code to add "width: 50%; height: auto;" undoes- the effect.